# Регулярные выражения в JS

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

Почему-то не могу запустить следующую регулярку на js:

```
    this.getText = function(){
      var reg = /(?<=.menu{)[^}]*$/
      let text1 = document.getElementById("css-mnu").innerText.search(reg);
      if (text1 == -1) return NaN;
      console.log(text1);
      let spl = text1.split(';');
      return spl;
    }
```

Сам текст:

> ```
>   .header{
>     min-height: 25px;        
>   }
>   .header *{
>     width: 100%;
>   }
>   .menu{
>     display: inline-flex;        
>     flex-direction: rows;
>     justify-content: space-around;        
>   }
>   .menu > *{
>     border: 1px solid;            
>     text-align: center;
>   }
>   .menu > *{
>     border: 1px solid;            
>     text-align: center;
>   }      
>   .menu *:last-child{
>     display: none;
>   }
> ```

Сама регулярка - рабочая. Проверял в notepad++, находит без проблем. При этом если саму регулярку упростить скажем до .menu, то тоже работает.

```js
var func = function(){

          var reg = /(?<=\.menu\{)[^\}]*$/
          let text1 = document.getElementById("css-mnu").innerText.search(reg);
          if (text1 == -1) 
            {
              document.write(text1);                         return NaN;
            }
          document.write(text1);
          let spl = text1.split(';');
          return spl;
        }
```

```html
    <div style="border:1px solid;cursor:pointer" onclick=func() id="css-mnu">
      /*все элементы меню имеют толщину 100%*/
      .header{
        min-height: 25px;        
      }
      .header *{
        width: 100%;
      }
      .menu{
        display: inline-flex;        
        flex-direction: rows;
        justify-content: space-around;        
      }
      .menu > *{
        border: 1px solid;            
        text-align: center;
      }
      .menu > *{
        border: 1px solid;            
        text-align: center;
      }      
      .menu *:last-child{
        display: none;
      }
      </div>
```

В чем может быть проблема с полной версией `/(?<=.menu{)[^}]*$/` ?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: `lookbehind` пока не работает в `js`

Comment: Вы ищите элемент с ID `css-mnu` - возможно тут опечатка должно быть `css-menu`

Comment: @ThisMan, работает, но не везде.

Comment: Используйте захватывающие подмаски. `document.getElementById("css-mnu").innerText.match(/\.menu{([^}]*)/)[1]`

Comment: `innerText` лучше не использовать.

Comment: @Qwertiy , а что использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте захватывающие подмаски, поддержка блоков предварительного просмотра назад (`(?<=...)`) появилась только в ECMAScript 2018:

```
var m = document.getElementById("css-mnu").innerText.match(/\.menu{([^}]*)/);
if (m) {
    return m[1].split(';');
} // else  ...
```

Демо:

```js
var str = " .header{\n    min-height: 25px;        \n  }\n  .header *{\n    width: 100%;\n  }\n  .menu{\n    display: inline-flex;        \n    flex-direction: rows;\n    justify-content: space-around;        \n  }\n  .menu > *{\n    border: 1px solid;            \n    text-align: center;\n  }\n  .menu > *{\n    border: 1px solid;            \n    text-align: center;\n  }      \n  .menu *:last-child{\n    display: none;\n  }";
var m = str.match(/\.menu{([^}]*)/);
if (m) {
  console.log(m[1].trim().split(/\s*;\s*/).filter(Boolean));
}
```

**Подробности**

- `\.` - символ `.` (должен быть экранирован, чтобы находить только символ `.`)
- `menu{` - нахожит `menu{`
- `([^}]*)` - Захватывающая подмаска (группа), которая находит 0 и более символов, отличных от `}` (`[^}]` — это исключающий символьный класс) и помещает найденное значение в отдельный буфер памяти (`m[1]`).